# How to prove that these Darboux functions are continuous?

Tags: continuity

Let $f$ be a   function defined on $[0,2]$ with the following properties:

i) If $[a,b] \subset [0,\infty],$ then $f([a,c])$ contains the interval with extremes  $f(a)$ and $f(b).$

ii) For all $c \in \Bbb R, $  the set $f^{-1}(c)$ is open.

Prove that $f$ is not continous on $[0,1]$

Comment: I think you need to edit this. You state $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ then ask to prove it is continuous on $[0,1]$.

Comment: I've edited your question a little. I hope it's ok. Now I think you should come up with a better title.

Comment: You're right, thank you.

Comment: Which title you would recommend ?

Comment: What about: How to prove that these [Darboux functions](http://planetmath.org/generalizeddarbouxfunction) are continuous? Indeed, the first condition says that $f$ satisfies the conclusion of the intermediate value theorem. Such functions are called Darboux functions.

Comment: I'll go with that, thank you.

Comment: Why did you change the question...? Now it does not make sense. If $f$ is defined on $[0,2]$ you can only consider $[a,b]\subseteq [0,2]$ in property i). Other than that, it does not change anything anyway and my answer still applies. Have you looked at it, by the way? Do you need details?

Answer (score 2):

First, observe that property i) says that $f$ satisfies the conclusion of the intermediate value theorem. Such functions are called [Darboux functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_%28analysis%29). They are not necessarily continuous.

Let us prove that for a Darboux function on $[0,1]$: $f$ is sequentially continuous (hence continuous, since we are dealing with metric spaces) if and only if $f^{-1}(\{c\})$ is closed for every $c\in\mathbb{R}$. The forward implication is trivial. We will prove the converse by contrapositive.

So assume there exists $x_0\in[0,1]$ and a sequence $(x_n)$ which converges to $x_0$ in $[0,1]$, such that $(f(x_n))$ does not converge to $f(x_0)$. This means that there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $N$, there exists $n\geq N$ such that $|f(x_n)-f(x_0)|\geq \epsilon$, i.e. $f(x_0)+\epsilon\leq f(x_n)$ or $f(x_n)+\epsilon\leq f(x_0)$.

These two conditions can't be both realized by a finite number of elements of the sequence. So assume the former is fulfilled for infinitely many $n$'s. A similar argument will reach the desired conclusion in case it is only the second inequality which is satisfied infinitely many times.

So up to an extraction, we can assume that $f(x_0)<c:=f(x_0)+\epsilon\leq f(x_n)$ for all $n$. By the Darboux property i), this yields for every $n$ the existence of some $y_n$ between $x_0$ and $x_n$ such that $f(y_n)=c$. Then $y_n\in f^{-1}(\{c\})$ converges to $x_0\not \in  f^{-1}(\{c\})$. So $f^{-1}(\{c\})$ is not closed for this $c$.